# What mental illnesses cause different performance on the Wisconsin Card Sorting Task

Tags: cognitive-psychology, abnormal-psychology, reference-request

I am aware that the Wisconsin Card Sorting Task (WCST) has been used multiple times to demonstrate [differences in executive function control in schizophrenics](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1407748/), but what other mental illness sufferers have been demonstrated to have significant performance differences on the WCST?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The diseases and mental dysfunctions that have been studied are Parkinson's disease, Huntington's disease, [ADHD](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15260171), [Substance Dependence](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2872109/), [Autism](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/228108070_Cognitive_flexibility_in_autism_spectrum_disorder_Explaining_the_inconsistencies), [Multiple Sclerosis](http://openi.nlm.nih.gov/detailedresult.php?img=2996259_fnhum-04-00219-a001&req=4) and Schizophrenia (with and without tardive dyskenisia). I'll add more specific statistics (such as trials required to acquire first rule) and better references later.

In the meantime, during my search I found this really quick table:
[image: table_of_disorders] from [this paper](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/089892900562174) showing the amount of completed categories and preservative errors (when a person is ignoring that the rule has changed).

Comment: psychosis is not found this way maybe a comorbid diseases but not psychosis.